# Retrieve S3 filenames, group by 3 digit number with related images in series then split series into columns and new group into new row

Tags: powershell, csv, amazon-s3, split, group-object

I'm attempting to use a CSV to bulk upload listings however the image urls are in columns.

I'm using Amazon S3 to host the images and PowerShell to retrieve the keys of each file. However I am unsure how to group by their related files and then use something like text to columns to split?

The files have a consistent naming structure:

```
C2-123-1.JPG
C2-123-2.JPG
C2-123-3.JPG
C3-333-1.JPG
C3-333-2.JPG
```

In the example above C2-123 has three photos, C2-333 has only two so I'm looking to receive an outcome like below.

```
|Image Link 1|  Image Link 2|   Image Link 3|   Image Link 4|
|C2-123-1.JPG|  C2-123-2.JPG|   C2-123-3.JPG|               |
|C3-333-1.JPG|  C3-333-2.JPG|               |               |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, you should replace `$data` for the output you get from AWS.

- Using `$data` for testing:

```
$data = @'
C2-123-1.JPG
C2-123-2.JPG
C2-123-3.JPG
C3-333-1.JPG
C3-333-2.JPG
C3-333-4.JPG
C3-333-999.JPG
C3-456-2.JPG
C3-111-2.JPG
C3-999-4.JPG
'@ -split '\r?\n'
```

- First, group by the numbers between the last `-` and the `.jpg` extension:

```
Count Name    Group
----- ----    -----
    2 1       {C2-123-1.JPG, C3-333-1.JPG}
    4 2       {C2-123-2.JPG, C3-333-2.JPG, C3-456-2.JPG, C3-111-2.JPG}
    1 3       {C2-123-3.JPG}
    2 4       {C3-333-4.JPG, C3-999-4.JPG}
    1 999     {C3-333-999.JPG}
```

- Then get the maximum number of elements of the `Group` arrays
- Lastly, use a `while` loop with `$max` as reference to cast `[pscustomobject]`

```
# Group the files
$groups = $data | Group-Object {

    [regex]::Match(
        $_,
        '(?i)(?<=\d-)(?<imagenum>\d+)\.jpg$'
    ).Groups['imagenum'].Value

}

# Determine max number of elements
$max = $groups.Count | Measure-Object -Maximum
$index = 0

# Construct the object
$result = while($max.Maximum--)
{
    $out = [ordered]@{}
    $groups.ForEach({
        $key = 'Image Link {0}' -f $_.Name
        $out[$key] = $_.Group[$index]
    })

    [pscustomobject]$out
    $index++
}
```

Result would be:

```
PS /> $result | Format-Table


Image Link 1 Image Link 2 Image Link 3 Image Link 4 Image Link 999
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ --------------
C2-123-1.JPG C2-123-2.JPG C2-123-3.JPG C3-333-4.JPG C3-333-999.JPG
C3-333-1.JPG C3-333-2.JPG              C3-999-4.JPG 
             C3-456-2.JPG                           
             C3-111-2.JPG
```

To see the `regex` explanation you can use https://regex101.com/r/kARr39/1

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much! Worked perfectly and taught me several things! Can't thank you enough!

Comment: @RyanJamison happy to help! and glad you learnt something new

Comment: I ran into an issue where if a SKU has more images than the others it correctly adds a column but it goes to the top row instead of the row with the corresponding serialized images. I can't even begin to think how that would be done. I thought to have a loop that checks the last column row by row to see if the middle number matches and if not insert white space to shift the entry down until it matches.

Comment: @RyanJamison Could you ask a new question explaining the problem with an example to have a better perspective, remember, add the data as text not screenshots